# How to remove Lightning Component Button from a page under certain conditions?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, custom-button, button

I have a button on a custom object which was built as a lightning component. I want to remove the button once the custom object has a Status updated to 'Completed'. Do I do this in code or is there a more simple way? If I need to do in code, what is an example of such code in simple form?

Comment: How is the button implemented, using Quick Action?

Comment: Yeah. It is in the normal Quick Action location, but located in Lightning Components. I didn't build it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot remove a button (in this case a Quick Action) based on condition of a record. Buttons are driven from page layout and that there's no direct way to render a different page layout based on different conditions of records.

Below are some options here, that you can evaluate based on your requirements.

1. If you want to completely remove the button based on condition of the record, you will need to introduce a new record type for this purpose. Create a new record type for records in status completed. Create new page layout for such record type, remove the button from the layout and assign the page layout for that record type.
2. Keep the button as is on the page layout, but provide a message that you cannot perform the expected operation if the status is completed, whenever the button is clicked. You will need to make changes in your Lightning Component to achieve such validation.